# Getting "ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision" in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

I use this script to insert data to my database:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    include('koneksi.php');

    $gid = pg_escape_string ($_POST['gid']);
    $nama = pg_escape_string ($_POST['nama']);
    $alamat = pg_escape_string ($_POST['alamat']);
    $no_telfon = pg_escape_string ($_POST['no_telfon']);
    $email = pg_escape_string ($_POST['email']);
    $website = pg_escape_string ($_POST['website']);
    $longitude = pg_escape_string ($_POST['longitude']);
    $latitude = pg_escape_string ($_POST['latitude']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO perguruantinggi( gid, nama, alamat, no_telfon, email, website, longitude, latitude ) 
    VALUES ('" . $gid . "', '" . $nama . "', '" . $alamat . "', '" . $no_telfon . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $website . "', '" . $longitude . "', '" . $latitude . "')";
    $result = pg_exec($query);

    //$query = "INSERT INTO perguruantinggi (username, password, fullname, email, agama, no_hp) 
    //VALUES ('" . $username . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $fullname . "', '" . $agama . "', '" . $no_hp . "')" ;


    if (!$result) {
        $errormessage = pg_last_error();
        echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
        exit();
    }
    printf ("These values were inserted into the database - %s %s %s", $firstname, $surname, $emailaddress);
    pg_close();
    ?>
</body>
```

I found this error when I compile this script. I use double precision for coordinate data type.

> Warning: pg_exec() [function.pg-exec]: Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision:

Comment: So what is the value of the string `$query` which is passed to `pg_exec()`?

Comment: I think for double, you don't need to add quotes (`"`) when you specify the values in your query.

Answer (score 3):

Manual quoting should be avoided, since it's both error prone and subject to potential injection attacks.

Most *SQL* libraries have a function which takes parameters, and uses placeholders in the query. The library takes care of the quoting, and prevents injection points.

Your best approach for this code is probably to use [`pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php), which allows you to pass the parameters as an array, and takes care of escaping for you. You use `$1`, `$2`, etc. in the query as placeholders.

So basically your `VALUES` clause would be replaced by `($1, $2, $3...)` and so on, with the values being passed to `pg_query_params` instead of interpolated directly.

Answer (score 2):

Combined with what @khampson says, I think your core issue is that you're quoting your `latitude` and `longitude` fields, which I am guessing are NOT strings but are doubles with precision. But you're parsing them as strings from the PHP `$_POST` and building your SQL query as if they were strings.

So you should do two things:

1. Use `pg_query_params`
2. When you build your array of values to pass
   to `pg_query_params` ensure you cast those values to a float. This
   is so that `pg_query_params` can have appropriate knowledge of the
   type so that it knows **NOT** to quote it as a string but to treat
   it as a raw numeric type.

Micro example:

```
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

$params = array(floatval($latitude), floatval($longitude));

$query = "INSERT INTO table (latitude, longitude) VALUES ($1, $2)";
pg_query_params($connection, $query, params);
```

Comment: Thank for yous answer mister, finaly i can fix this problem.